# How to pass array elements in constructor?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment in which I have a constructor having a name and a result array that contains the marks for 5 subjects. I created a constructor and passed `Name` and `Array` using a for loop. But when I created the object of the `Student` class in the `Main` class to pass the arguments in constructor it gives a syntax error.

How can I pass the array elements in constructor?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {

    private String Name;
    private Array[] obj =new Array[5];
 //   private int Student1, Student2;
   // private int m1=450, m2=333;

    // constructor
    Student(String Name, int Array[]){
        this.Name=Name;
        for(int i=0; i<Array.length; i++ )
        {
            Array[0]=9;
            Array[1]=34;
            Array[2]=88;
            Array[3]=56;
            Array[4]=33;
        }
    }
        // Average method
        public void Average(){
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the marks of Student 1:");
             Student1=input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the marks of Student 2:");
            Student2=input.nextInt();   
        }}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
       Student ss=new Student(Name, Array);
Student ss=new Student(Name, i[87]);
    }
```

Comment: your constructor expects an array, not an int

Comment: but array should have an datatype

Comment: ok ... it expects an array of ints, not an int.

Comment: Is the use of `java.lang.reflect.Array` required by this assignment?

Comment: No java.lang.reflect.Array is not required for this assignment

Comment: Then I suggest not to use it but use simple `int[]` or `String[]`.

Comment: Pick up your text book and read the section about arrays, your grades array should most likely be something like `int[] grades`

Comment: should i post my assignment question. I think it will be helpful to understand the whole situation.

Comment: How can i modify my code please guide me

Comment: by sending your array, not just one element of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your int[] array into the Student constructor, not build the array inside it.

I'd swap this line

```
private Array[] obj =new Array[5];
```

for

```
private int[] grades = new int[5];
```

In your main method, build your grades for your new student object `int[] ssGrades = new int[5];` Then assign your values as you have in your student constructor below that so `ssGrades[0] = 9` etc.

In your student constructor, replace

```
Student(String Name, int Array[])
```

for

```
Student(String name, int[] grades);
```

because you want to send your constructor an integer array, not an int called Array[]. Then pass this into the Student constructor:

`Student ss = new Student(name, ssGrades[]);`

Then in your student class you want to say that `this.Name = Name` as you have done, but then

```
this.grades = grades;
```

I think you need to separate in your head the difference between an object that's `Array[]`, and object that's `int[] varName` as well as what is a property being assigned to an object and the object itself.

Your problems have come from your code naming variables in a way that makes it confusing for you to use, in my opinion.

Also, you don't need a for loop when you're not using the index of the for loop. All that

```
for(int i=0; i < Array.length;i++){
  Array[0] = 9;
  etc
}
```

is doing the filling of your array with the same values (Array.length) amount of times (because there's no use of your index i, nor can you use it because the grades you're trying to input in are not dependent on i).
I hope this answer helps.